# Ошибка StackOverflowError

Tags: java, android

Я нажимаю на "Играть" - главный слой скрывается (Visible.GONE) и срабатывает анимация перехода на другой слой. И если я закончу/прерву игру, то бишь просто перейду на главный экран с помощью `Navigation Drawer`, то он перейдет без ошибок, все хорошо. Но если я так повторю 11 раз (нажимая на "Играть" и завершать/покидать тест), то вылетает ошибка `StackOverflowError`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnPlay:
            visibility(3);
            break;

        case R.id.row1:
            visibility(4);
            recyclerViewInitialize(1);
            break;

        case R.id.answer1:
            animObj.animateConsoleOut();
            methodForButtonInLayoutRows(0, 1);

            break;

        case R.id.answer2:
            animObj.animateConsoleOut();
            methodForButtonInLayoutRows(2, 3);
            break;

        case R.id.answer3:
            animObj.animateConsoleOut();
            methodForButtonInLayoutRows(4, 5);
            break;
    }
}
```

`btnPlay` - Играть. Здесь работает метод `visibility`, который скроет главное меню и покажет другой слой.

```
visibility(3)
layoutSection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
selectSectionTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
layoutRow1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
animObj.animateSubSection();
```

`row1` - Открывает разделы (программирование и прочее)

```
visibility(4)
layoutSection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
selectSectionTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
layoutRow1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
animObj.animateSubSection();


 // ПЕРЕХОДЫ С NAVIGATION DRAWER
private void visibleNavigation(int pos){
    switch (pos){
        case 0:
            scrollOfQuestAndAnswer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scrollMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            animObj.animateChooseNavigation(pos);
            break;
    }
}
```

answer1,2,3 это кнопки вариантов ответа, в которых происходит вызывается новый вопрос и ответы

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawText(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:256)
at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:345)
at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:205)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4886)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13458)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12409)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1555)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12409)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12409)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:
```

Comment: Думаю нужен код.

Comment: картинки излишне, покажите код

Comment: Я не понимаю почему переполнение стека происходит. Ведь там работает по сути VISIBLE и все. Он то делает видимым главное меню, то просто его скрывает переходя на слой, где происходит сама игра